# In propositional logic how is the negation equivalent?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

I am unable to understand how the negation of a sentence into CNF actually makes sense, hopefully somebody can explain it to me in understandable terms!

Given the sentence: ***If the battery is charged (A) and the screen is not cracked (B) then the phone is working (C)***

The following makes perfect sense:

`(A ∧ B) => C`

I cannot get my head around how the negated form is true or how it works:

`¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C`

I am struggling because "not A" means if the battery is not charged? So I cannot see how if the battery is not charged ***or*** the "screen is cracked" **or** the "phone is usable".

If A is false, so battery is not charged, how is that applying ¬A to it does not make it now true?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess your negated formula is wrong? How do you get $\neg B \lor C$ from $B \implies C$?

Comment: Maybe it is, can you explain a little more about what you mean? I took it to mean "its not charged, or the screen is cracked, or it works"

Comment: I missed something out...so nevermind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to accept and understand, that $A \Rightarrow C$ is same as $(\neg A) \lor C$. Using your example we obtain, that "**If the battery is charged, then the phone is working**" is same with "**the battery is not charged or the phone is working**".

Now following initial sentence $(A \land B) \Rightarrow C$ we have $\neg(A \land B) \lor C$, where last sounds as "**not fulfilling (the battery is charged and the screen is not cracked) or (the phone is working)**".

Now we come to negation of $\neg(A \land B) = (\neg A) \lor (\neg B)$. So sentence "**not fulfilling (the battery is charged and the screen is not cracked)**" is same as "**(the battery is not charged) or  (the screen is cracked)**"

Putting everything together we have
$$(A \land B) \Rightarrow C \text{ is same with } (\neg A)  \lor (\neg B) \lor C $$

in words last is "**(the battery is not charged) or  (the screen is cracked) or (the phone is working)**"

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense and is what I was missing. The only thing still confusing me now is how the OR's are executed, so it is not to be read like a set of OR statements inside an if condition, more like an if else (the final OR being the else)? Or should I not try to liken this to if conditions?

Comment: "then .. if.." becomes, or more exactly, **is** "not .. or.." - this is one of the most confusing moments in mathematical implication. More human may be sounds "or not .. or..". One example: "if I have money, then I'll buy book" is same with "or I haven't money or I'll buy book". So implication is not set of "or"s inside "if", but "if" itself **is** "or not .. or..".  Continuing..

Comment: Continuation. If you look more closer, on some next step in future, then you'll see, that in truth table such definition of implication gives "strange" behaviour when premise of implication is false: despite of what conclusion is - true or false - whole implication become true.

Comment: Ok so its much more like a human readable sentence in theory